# Why is my C++ code for Antoinne vapor pressure not working?

Tags: c++

The C++ code below keeps giving me a nearly constant output of (0.999976..) as calculated by the Psat() function, whereas, the value is supposed to change meaningfully when I adjust saturation temperature, Tsat???

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

class components{
    private:
        double A, B, C, Tsat;
    public:
        void AntParam(double A, double B, double C, double Tsat){
               A = A, B = B, C = C, Tsat = Tsat ;}
        void Psat(){cout << "Vapor Pressure is "
                         <<pow(10,(A - B/(C + Tsat)))<<" torr"<<endl;}
                };

int main(){
    components water;
        water.AntParam(8.07131, 1730.63, 233.426, 100);
        water.Psat();
        return 0; };
```

Comment: I strongly recommend [turning on your compiler warnings](https://godbolt.org/z/3MzMvzjE4).  They want to help you!

Comment: Please check your parameters. This table provides different [coefficients for water](https://vacuu-lan.com/vapor-pressure-estimates-antoine-equation/). !00 K is outside the useful range for the Antoinne equation.

Answer (score 2):

The deep, dark secret is [Shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing). The `double A` parameter is narrower in scope than `double A` the member variable, so the parameter is the sole owner of the identifier `A` inside the function. You could `this->A = A,...`, you could use the member's full name `components::A = A, ...`, you could rename the parameter, or you could rename the member variable.

Me, I'd use a constructor and make use of the member initializer list.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

class components
{
private:
    double A, B, C, Tsat;
public:
    components(double A, double B, double C, double Tsat):
        A(A), B(B), C(C), Tsat(Tsat)
    {

    }
    void Psat()
    {
        cout << "Vapor Pressure is " << pow(10, (A - B / (C + Tsat))) << " torr"
                << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    components water(8.07131, 1730.63, 233.426, 100);
    water.Psat();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your insight, the modified code achieved the result. Though I later added two more objects i.e ether and ethanol to the class constructor (components), and got their values also.  Can I do something to the code to make it display object names in association with calculated object values. Is this possible?

Comment: @chenon I'd add a `std::string` member to `components` that holds the name so I could print it out as needed.